# Find previous elements on the page

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="cv1">Upload your CV</label>
    <div class="row-holder">
        <input type="file" name="ctl00$main$rptJobs$ctl02$fileuploadcv" id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fileuploadcv" class="updatename" style="display:none;" />
        <input name="ctl00$main$rptJobs$ctl02$fucv1" type="text" id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fucv1" class="upload" />
        <label id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fucvlabel" class="uploadbtn" for="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fileuploadcv">BROWSE</label>                                                    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="letter1">Upload letter of application</label>
    <div class="row-holder">
        <input type="file" name="ctl00$main$rptJobs$ctl02$fileuploadcl" id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fileuploadcl" class="updatename" style="display:none;" />
        <input name="ctl00$main$rptJobs$ctl02$fucl1" type="text" id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fucl1" class="upload" />
        <label id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fucllabel" class="uploadbtn" for="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_fileuploadcl">BROWSE</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-holder">                                                    
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$main$rptJobs$ctl02$btnSubmit" value="Send" id="ctl00_main_rptJobs_ctl02_btnSubmit" class="jqueryvalidate" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's start with the HTML:

Please note that this is a sample of the DOM from a repeater. I'm trying to validate that the fileuploads aren't empty. It's the class "upload" that has to contain a value. The `input class="upload"` has a dynamic id that is created by the repeater so can only be referenced by it's class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.jqueryvalidate').click(function() {
        var tempcv;
        var tempcl;
        tempcv = $(this).prev().prev().prev().find(".upload");
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've tried `.prev()`, `.parent()` and `.find() but always get`undefined`. Can anyone spot where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: I see two `<input>`s with class "upload". Which one do you to select?

Comment: better code would be `$(this).closest('.row').find('.upload')` so that you don't get screwed if you had another level in between .row and .jqueryvalidate

Comment: @Guillaume `closest('.row')` will point to the same "row", where `this` element exists, while you need its siblings.

Comment: have you only one "jqueryvalidate" button or meny?

Comment: I need to check both inputs. Just trying to find one of them for now.  Would $(this).closest('.row').closest('.row').find('.upload') find the previous?

@Nishan, there would be many on the page

Comment: @AndrewHales no .closest('.row').closest('.row') would search in the parents of the first .row an element having class "row". You need to search for the siblings of it.  I highly recommand you to look at the different [DOM traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) jquery provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missundersand [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), prev is for the previous sibling. What you wanted to use is [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Any way as I said in the comment and AsciiSmoke sugests too, using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) would make it more maintanable as you are less dependent of the DOM hierarchie

```
$(this).closest('.row').siblings('.row').find('.upload')
```

- .closest('.row') finds the parent row of the clicked input
- .siblings('.row') finds all siblings row of the previous row
- .find('.upload') finds all .upload in the set of rows find before.

Comment: this worked, a treat, something new added to my jquery knowledge as well.  Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Stackoverflow is here to improve our knowledge ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzmwrvaL/1/)

```
tempcv = $(this).closest('.row').siblings().find(".upload");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead. This traverses backwards up the tree until it finds the element you're looking for. Then work back down to the upload.

Alternatively, try creating a unique class name for the upload on each row.

i.e. something like:

<asp:button CssClass="submit_button_<%#Eval ("recordId") %>" runat="server">

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I suggest try below code, this will return the collection of uploads.
Brower's developer tool like Mozilla's firebug will be of much help, in console or by setting up the breakpoint in js code you can find out the details.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input.jqueryvalidate').click(function() {
            var tempcv;
            var tempcl;
            tempcv = $('.row').find(".upload");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.jqueryvalidate').click(function() {
        var tempcv;
        var tempcl;
        tempcv = $(this).closest(".row").siblings(".row").find(".upload");
        tempcv.each(function(){
            alert(this.id)

        });

        //return false;
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s1ttccr5/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate all `.upload` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.jqueryvalidate').click(function() {
        var $uploads = $('.row .upload');
        var valid = true;
        $uploads.each(function () {
            if (!this.value) {
                valid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return valid;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.jqueryvalidate').click(function () {
            $temp = $('div.row').find(".upload");
            $temp.each(function () {
                // do something here
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```